# Is the Mycetozoa phylum part of Amoebozoa or Protozoa kingdom?

Tags: mycology

I'm not sure if the two kingdoms are essentially the same thing. I was looking at mushroom data collected by citizen scientists, and a lot of the data is labeled as belonging to one of three kingdoms: fungi, protozoa, and amoebozoa. However I don't really understand the difference between protozoa and amoebozoa.